# What is more reactive towards a cyanohydrin formation an aldehyde or an Ketone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, reactivity

Which is more reactive—aldehydes or ketones—towards the nucleophilic addition by cyanide to form cyanohydrins?

Answer (score 1):

Aldehydes will generally form cyanohydrins more readily than ketones, but some ketones such as trifluoromethyl or acyl ketones may behave more like aldehydes due to the electron deficiency at carbonyl carbon.